# UIImage passed to method on another thread crashes CGContextDraw with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, uiimage, core-graphics

I am currently working on an app which requires me to do some image processing. So I have the user take an image and all steps of the processing are shown. Thus I create a grey-scale version of the image, pass it to the processing class (by setting of its property) and then call its processing method on another thread (by using `dispatch_async()`). The problem is when I try to draw the passed image into the context to retrieve the data in order to use it with OpenGL, the app crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=1`. Below is the code in question:

---

ProcessorViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // Create Grayscale
    UIImage *grayScaleImage = [self createGrayScaleOfImage:theImage];
    processor = [[GLKProcessor alloc] init];
    [processor setOriginalImage:grayScaleImage];
    [self.view addSubview:processor.Step1View];

    // Run OpenGL ES processing on seperate dispatch_queue
    dispatch_queue_t processing = dispatch_queue_create("com.CannyEdgeDetectoriOS.processing", nil);
    dispatch_async(processing, ^{
        [processor beginImageProcessingWithGrayScaleImage];
    });
}
```

---

GLKProcessor.h

```
@interface GLKProcessor : NSObject <GLKViewDelegate> {
    GLKView *Step1View;
    GLKView *Step2View;
    GLKView *Step3View;

    @private
    //__strong UIImage *originalImage;
    CIContext *ciContext;
}

@property (strong) GLKView *Step1View;
@property (strong) GLKView *Step2View;
@property (strong) GLKView *Step3View;

@property (strong) EAGLContext *currentEAGLContext;

@property (strong) UIImage *originalImage;

- (void)beginImageProcessingWithGrayScaleImage;

@end
```

---

GLKProcessor.m

```
#pragma mark - Start Call
- (void)beginImageProcessingWithGrayScaleImage {
    // Draw originalImage(grayScale) in GLKView and blur
    [self glkView:Step1View drawInRect:Step1View.frame];
    [Step1View display];
}



#pragma mark - GLKViewDelegate
- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Check which glkView
    switch ([view tag]) {
        case 0: {
            // Step1 GLKView
            // Draw originalImage(grayScale) in GLKView
            ciContext = [CIContext contextWithEAGLContext:self.currentEAGLContext];
            // Check EAGLContext
            if (self.currentEAGLContext != [EAGLContext currentContext]) {
                [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.currentEAGLContext];
            }

            [Step1View bindDrawable];
            // Clear EAGLContext to white
            glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            /* * * * * * * Draw grayscale image * * * * * * */
            CGImageRef cgOriginalImage = [originalImage CGImage];

            // Declare variables
            GLuint texture;
            size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(cgOriginalImage);
            size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(cgOriginalImage);
            size_t bytesPerPixel = CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(cgOriginalImage);
            size_t bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
            size_t bitsPerComponenet = CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(cgOriginalImage);
            GLubyte *glBytes = (GLubyte *)malloc(bytesPerRow * height);

            // Draw image to context
            CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceGenericGray);
            CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(&glBytes, width, height, bitsPerComponenet, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNone);
            CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace); // Release color space to clear unneeded memory allocation
            CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), cgOriginalImage);
            CGContextRelease(context); // Release context to clear uneeded memory allocation

            // OpenGL ES workings
            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
            glGenTextures(1, &texture);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, (int)width, (int)height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, glBytes);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

            break;
        }

        case 1:
            // Step2 GLKView
            break;

        case 2:
            // Step3 GLKView
            break;

        default:
            // Error
            break;
    }
}
```

---

I have tried to analyse the issue myself, by setting a breakpoint in the ProcessorViewController and then 'stepping' through the code. What I have noticed is that the variables (`size_t width`, `size_t height`, etc...) I set are all expected values until the `CGImageRef` is reached in the `CGContextDrawImage()` method. Once that occurs the values skyrocket and all properties of the NSObject are set to nil.

I am completely new to threads, and don't really understand what is going on. Might it have something to do with the fact that the grey-scale image was allocated and initialised on another thread? If so how could I get around this issue, I really want to have the processing done on another thread so that the UI is still responsive.

Thank you so much for any insights/suggestions/help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: What happens when you call beginImageProcessingWith.…on the main thread?

Comment: @beyowulf as in calling the method on the main frame and then in the method dispatching the processing to a different thread?

Comment: Well yes. But before you do any of that just comment out dispatch_queue_t processing = dispatch_queue_create("com.CannyEdgeDetectoriOS.processing", nil);
    dispatch_async(processing, ^{ }]; and see if allowing beginImageProcessingWithGrayScaleImage to block works.

Comment: @beyowulf So your idea was very good, it doesn't seem to be an issue with the tread, since I still get the issue with the variables getting insanely large values. (example width(before) = 2448 and width(after) = 216456464737370369) and the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` still occurs

Comment: Think bad access is caused by this line:             CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace); // Release color space to clear unneeded memory allocation

Comment: @beyowulf I moved the `CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);` to after the `CGContextDrawImage()` but I still get the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` and the weird variables